# Contexts in Liquibase, Run in Any Contexts But One

Tags: liquibase

Lets say I have my contexts set to 'development'

Where the other two contexts used by the application will be 'production' and 'test'

I have two changesets:

```
<changeSet id="test-1" author="dbadmin" context="!development">
    <sql>
        CREATE TABLE test_table_1 (
        ID int
        );
    </sql>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="test-2" author="dbadmin" context="development">
    <sql>
        CREATE TABLE test_table_2 (
        ID int
        );
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

I would expect while the context is set to 'development' the second changeset would run, and while its set to 'production' or 'test' the first changeset should run.

What I'm seeing in testing is '!development' is never run, no matter what the context is set too. Am I misunderstanding the '!' operator for the contexts?

EDIT:

Calling liquibase via command line, passing in --context=${contexts} where $contexts is a bash variable

Using liquibase 3.1.1

Comment: What version of liquibase are you using?

Comment: My understanding of the operator ist the same. It should work. Maybe something else is missing... You could edit your question and add how you call liquibase and how you specify the running context.